# How to configure and display a custom ratio metric data in Google Analytics 4 report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm new to GA4 and want to integrate my web application to view user stay duration data per page path.
I defined the event trigger of 'Stay Duration' in GTM. I've a custom report like this in GA4:

| Page Path | Stay Duration | Visit Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /list | 400s | 3 |
| /profile | 150s | 2 |
| /role | 100s | 1 |

Currently, once 'Visit Count' increases 1, this new stay duration time value will be added into 'Stay Duration'

I want to show the average stay duration value of every page path, not to show them in total. Something like stay duration/visit count.

How can display those kind of ratio metric (average stay duration) in GA4 report? Do I need to change the tags/triggers definition in GTM?